# Perl script and regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I have string like this:

```
constant = 0.015
history = 90
[thresholds]
up = 100
down = -100
persistence = 0
[thresholds]
up = 100
down = -100
persistence = 0
```

I must convert it to format like this:

```
config.n8_v2_BB_RSI_SL = {
constant: 0.015,
history: 90,
thresholds: {
up: 100,
down: -100,
persistence: 0 },
thresholds: {
up: 100,
down: -100,
persistence: 0 }
};
```

I did all without closing bracket in first [thresholds]. I havent idea how do this.
My work:

```
$a =~ s/(?<!\])(?=[\n])/,/g;
$a =~ s/ =/:/g;
$a =~ s/(?<![\D\d])/config.n8_v2_BB_RSI_SL = {\n/g;
$a =~ s/\[//g;
$a =~ s/\]/: {/g;

  if ($a =~ /: \{/) {
$a =~ s/(?![\n\D\d])/ \}/g;
}
$a =~ s/(?![\n\D\d])/\n\};/g;


print "$a \n"; 
config.n8_v2_BB_RSI_SL = {
constant: 0.015,
history: 90,
thresholds: {
up: 100,
down: -100,
persistence: 0,
thresholds: {
up: 100,
down: -100,
persistence: 0 }
};
```

After `persistence: 0` I must add `},`. How do it? [thresholds] can appear more than 1 times, or never appear.

Comment: I would use an INI parser to get the input data into a Perl data structure, then convert that to JSON.

Comment: Also, don't use `$a`. It's a reserved global variable for use in `sort` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = '...';
my $expected = '...';

$input =~ s/ =/:/g;
$input =~ s/\[(.*)\]/}\n$1: {/g;
$input =~ s/^/config.n8_v2_BB_RSI_SL = {\n/;
$input =~ s/(?<!\{)$/,/mg;
$input =~ s/,\n}//;
$input =~ s/,\n}/ }/g;
$input =~ s/,$/ }\n};/;

$input eq $expected or die 'Different';
```

Comment: Its not work because "thresholds" is variable. Can have another name like [peaks]. I forgot write this.

Comment: @J.Doe: Fixed. You could have fixed it yourself, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps `use Config::IniFiles` to read input and `use JSON` to generate the output. (Is it JSON?)

Or...

Using a bag of dirty tricks, this:

```
my $s=join"",<DATA>;
my $n='00000001';
$s=~s/^(.*?)(\w+)/$1_@{[$n++]}_$2/gm;
$s=sz({conf($s)});
$s=~s,\b_(\d{8})_(\w+),$2,g;
print "config.n8_v2_BB_RSI_SL = $s;\n";
sub sz {my$c=shift;ref$c?"{\n".(join",\n",map{"$_: ".sz($$c{$_})}sort keys%$c)."}":$c}
sub conf{
  my($hr,$section)=({});
  my@r=(qr/^\s*\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]/,
        qr/^\s*([^\:\=]+?)\s*[:=]\s*(.*?)\s*$/);
  /$r[0]/ and                 $$hr{$section=$1}||={} or
  /$r[1]/ and defined$section?$$hr{$section}{$1}:$$hr{$1}=$2
    for split"\n",shift;
  %$hr;
}
__DATA__
constant = 0.015
history = 90
[thresholds]
up = 100
down = -100
persistence = 0
[thresholds]
up = 20
down = -100
persistence = 0
[peaks]
up = 100
down = -100
persistence = 0
```

Produces this:

```
config.n8_v2_BB_RSI_SL = {
constant: 0.015,
history: 90,
thresholds: {
up: 100,
down: -100,
persistence: 0},
thresholds: {
up: 20,
down: -100,
persistence: 0},
peaks: {
up: 100,
down: -100,
persistence: 0}};
```